# how to menage positions in arraylist android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have an array list
like this

```
position(Arraylist)   item_name
0                       abc
1                       chf
2                       tiy
3                       trf
4                       lkj
5                       xyz
```

but if i write `ArrayList.remove(0);` i get this

```
  position(Arraylist)   item_name

    0                       chf
    1                       tiy
    2                       trf
    3                       lkj
    4                       xyz
```

but i want it like this

```
  position(Arraylist)   item_name

    1                       chf
    2                       tiy
    3                       trf
    4                       lkj
    5                       xyz
```

i wish that you've undrestand me 
and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Then what you wan't isn't a list, its a Map<Integer, String>.  When you remove something from a list, it shifts the position of everything in the list.  If you want to associate 1 value with another for lookup purposes, that's a map.

Comment: arrayList are 0 based data containers... the 1st element in the list is pointed at zero...

Comment: If you do `ArrayList.remove(1)`, how does it remove "0   abc"? That should be remove(0)

Comment: Gabe Sechan i have never worked with map can you tell me how to use  it

Comment: Michael i mean ArrayList.remove(0)  sorry for my typo error

Answer (score 0):

What sou are trying to do is not possible, `ArrayList` are 0 based data containers... the 1st element in the list is pointed at index zero...

as soon as the list has a size > 0 there will be an element at index 0

Comment: i want to delete somthing without touching positions

Comment: can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Java arrays always start at 0 position. If you remove the position, you will remove the value of the first position and then, the second position will be the first position and etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that using List.. if you really want start with 1..using LinkedHashMap instead..

```
 LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
 hmap.put(1, "asdasd");
 hmap.put(2, "qwewewl");
 hmap.put(3, "sfsdffd");
 hmap.put(4, "ererer");
 hmap.put(5, "ggggggg");


 for(Map.Entry m:hmap.entrySet()){  
    System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
 }
```

To remove

```
hmap.remove(1);  //Use Key to remove
```

Comment: android studio says that "cannot resolve symbole  LinkedHashMap"

Comment: you need to import it.. `import java.util.LinkedHashMap;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [SparseArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

> Unlike a normal array of Objects, there can be gaps in the indices

Comment: how can i use it